# Sum of squares of Weber Modular Functions

Tags: number-theory, special-functions, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

Let $\tau\in\mathbb C$ such that $\mathrm{Im}\left(\tau\right)>0$. Define $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$. Then define the Weber modular functions as

$$
\mathfrak f\left(\tau\right)=q^{-\frac1{48}}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+q^{n-\frac12}\right)=e^{-\frac{i\pi}{24}}\frac{\eta\left(\frac{\tau+1}2\right)}{\eta\left(\tau\right)}=\frac{\eta\left(\tau\right)^2}{\eta\left(\frac\tau2\right)\eta\left(2\tau\right)}\\
\mathfrak f_1\left(\tau\right)=q^{-\frac1{48}}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-q^{n-\frac12}\right)=\frac{\eta\left(\frac\tau2\right)}{\eta\left(\tau\right)}\\
\mathfrak f_2\left(\tau\right)=\sqrt2q^{\frac1{24}}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+q^n\right)=\frac{\sqrt2\eta\left(2\tau\right)}{\eta\left(\tau\right)}
$$

Can
$$
S\left(\tau\right)=\mathfrak f\left(\tau\right)^2+\mathfrak f_1\left(\tau\right)^2+\mathfrak f_2\left(\tau\right)^2
$$
be written more compactly? Am I missing any helpful identites? This came up in a physics problem I was solving.

**Extra Question**

I managed to show that $S\left(\tau+8\right)=e^{-\frac{2\pi i}3}S\left(\tau\right)$, so I realised that this integral is interesting too:
$$
g\left(a\right)=\frac18\int_0^8\left\lvert S\left(b+ia\right)\right\rvert^2\mathrm db
$$
But I have no idea how to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Beside $\mathfrak{f}\mathfrak{f}_1\mathfrak{f}_2=\sqrt{2}$ and $\mathfrak{f}^8 = \mathfrak{f}_1^8 + \mathfrak{f}_2^8$ and easy identities like $\mathfrak{f}(\tau) = \frac{\mathfrak{f}_1(2\tau)}{\mathfrak{f}_1(\tau)}$, there is Legendre's modular equation $\mathfrak{f}(\tau)^2\mathfrak{f}(3\tau)^2 = \mathfrak{f}_1(\tau)^2\mathfrak{f}_1(3\tau)^2 + \mathfrak{f}_2(\tau)^2\mathfrak{f}_2(3\tau)^2$ that you might want to consider.

Comment: You might want to look at sums of Jacobi Thetanulls $(\Theta_{00},\Theta_{01},\Theta_{10}) = (\mathfrak{f}^2\eta,\mathfrak{f}_1^2\eta,\mathfrak{f}_2^2\eta)$ instead. E.g. $\Theta_{00}(\tau) + \Theta_{01}(\tau) = 2\Theta_{00}(4\tau)$.

Comment: More compactly in term of what functions ? $g(\tau)=\mathfrak f\left(\tau\right)^2+\mathfrak f_1\left(\tau\right)^2+\mathfrak f_2\left(\tau\right)^2 $ is in $M_0(\Gamma)$ so the first step is to find $\Gamma$, then $g$ will be a rational function of $j(\gamma_j(z))$ for a few $\gamma_j$ @ccorn

Comment: @reuns, being a physicist, I am not familiar with this. Can you maybe help me out and do it, maybe as as an answer?

Comment: @ccorn, can you tell me a reference for these thetanulls? I can't seem to find even the definitions online.

Comment: With Thetanulls I mean what Jacobi called Theta nullvalues, i.e. Jacobi Theta functions at $z=0$, as functions of $\tau$. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_Theta_function#Relations_to_Dedekind_eta_function) and [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/20). It is possible to write your $S$ as a sum of two theta quotients (each with fixed $z$), but I have not been able to get rid of the sum completely. $S$ is certainly not reducible to an eta quotient as it has zeros in $\mathbb{H}$. Also note the invariance of $S$ under $\tau\mapsto-\tau^{-1}$.

Comment: As to zeros of $S$: Algebraic eliminations show that $S(\tau)=0$ implies $\mathfrak{f}(\tau)^6 = 1$, which is equivalent to $\mathfrak{f}_1(2\tau)^6=\mathfrak{f}_1(\tau)^6$. This suggests to look for a modular transform $M$ that preserves $\mathfrak{f}_1^6$ and has a complex solution to $M(\tau) = 2\tau$. One example is $M=T^6 J T^{-1} J T^3 J T^{-3}$ where $T(\tau)=\tau+1$ and $J(\tau)=-\tau^{-1}$, resulting in $8\tau^2-53\tau+88 = 0$, and indeed $S(\tau)=0$ there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this answers your question:

> Can
> $$ S(\tau) = \mathfrak f(\tau)^2 + 
>  \mathfrak f_1(\tau)^2 + \mathfrak f_2(\tau)^2 $$
> be written more compactly?

As it is easily checked the sum $\,S\,$
is **not** an eta quotient,
as user 'ccorn' alluded to briefly in a
comment. Let us define $\,q:=e^{\pi i \tau},\,$
$$ S_1(\tau) :=\! \frac{\theta_3(0,q^2)}{\eta(\tau)}
 \!=\! \frac{\eta(4\tau)^5}{\eta(\tau)\, 
 \eta(2\tau)^2\, \eta(8\tau)^2}. \tag{1} $$
It is the G.F. of
[OEIS sequence A226622](https://oeis.org/A226622).
Now we get
$$ 2 S_1(\tau) \!=\! \mathfrak f(\tau)^2
\!+\! \mathfrak f_1(\tau)^2 \!=\! 
q^{-1/24}(2\!+\!2q\!+\!8q^2\!+ ...).  $$

Also let us define
$$ S_2(\tau) :=\! \frac{\theta_3(0,q)}{\eta(8\tau)}
\!=\! \frac{\eta(2\tau)^5}{\eta(\tau)^2
\eta(4\tau)^2\eta(8\tau)}. \tag{2} $$
This is an eta-quotient by definition and
$$ S_2(\tau/8) \!=\! \mathfrak f(\tau)^2 \!+\!
\mathfrak f_2(\tau)^2 \!=\! q^{-1/24}(
1 \!+\! 2q \!+\! 2q^4 \!+  ...).$$

Thus we get that
$$ S(\tau) = 2S_1(\tau)+\mathfrak f_2(\tau)^2= 
S_2(\tau/8) + \mathfrak f_1(\tau)^2. \tag{3} $$